# Make sails.js listen for remote connections

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

I want my development environment to be accessible from remote connections as well as local. I have changed my `local.js` config file to listen on port 80 and host 0.0.0.0.

[image]

`netstat -ab | more` output:

[image]

Port forwarding:

[image]

And my firewall is disabled. however, the app is not accessible via browser and remote IP, nor can it be seen by http://canyouseeme.org.
All the command prompt windows are run with lifted privileges.

I currently don't have the option to run it as `--prod` if that would change anything.

EDIT: Tried fixing problems with production environment, and running as --prod, still same problem. Also tried setting up the simplest possible node.js server, and it also had this same problem, which leads me to believe, that it's problems with my router, and not sails.js. Any ideas, what could be preventing this?

Answer (score 1):

Let's make your app listen on another port (for example 1337) then forward traffic from port 80 to port 1337.
Another way, you can use Nginx in front as a reverse proxy. By this way, Nginx will handle traffic on any port (80 as your requirement) and forward to your Sails app.

Hope this helped!